# http-equiv refresh & SEO

Tags: seo

I have web pages that may or may not need to do some pre-processing before it can be displayed to the user. What I have done is to display this page with a message (e.g. "please wait ..."), then do an http-equiv refresh **to the same page**. When it refreshes to the same page, the pre-processing is done and the actual content is displayed.

Will this harm me in terms of SEO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one can answer this question with a solid answer however a page that the content changes which seems to be a result of a form or something, this isn't something that should be indexed, you should probably disallow search engines from accessing that page by using robots.txt

Comment: The resulting page after the pre-processing does need to be indexed, though. I may need to use different pages (meaning, different URLs) and disallow the pre-processing page. What do you think?

Comment: If the resulting content has to be indexed, then you are much better off creating a different page for the generated content, instead of having a "Please wait.." page, you could utilize a 301 redirect using PHP, however that comes at the cost of not being able to display any message.

Comment: I used `http-equiv refresh` because 301 redirect was not an option. When I load the pre-processing page, the timer of `http-equiv refresh` doesn't start until the pre-processing is done. So, it seemed like the perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

This would really depend on the type of page/URL you are on and what type of content you are generating/selecting for the user.

The best option would be to have a "standard" version of the page and have that load by default. If the content should vary based on user/session or cookie SEs will only see the "default version". Be careful not to shoot yourself in the foot though. A user demonstrating the same behavior as a SE should also see the default content.